# "Joining" 2 different selects on the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of orders with products, each product has their own shipping date.  How can I retrieve the orders so it shows the fastest shipping date?

For example:

```
Order  Product  Ship date
1      phone    02/03/2019
1      charger  02/07/2019
2      printer  03/01/2019
```

What would be the sql query to retrieve the following?

```
Order  Product  Ship date
1      phone    02/03/2019
1      charger  02/03/2019
2      printer  03/01/2019
```

I.e on order 1, all ship dates are 02/03/2019 since it's the earliest.

I tried this:

```
SELECT order, 
       product,
       (SELECT ship_date FROM Tracking ORDER BY ship_date ASC) tbl ON tbl.order = t.order
FROM Tracking t
```

But I'm getting the error:

`The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the error message I believe this is for SQL Server and thus window functions to be available.

You could use the windowed version of `min()` to get the minimum shipping date for an order.

```
SELECT [order],
       [product],
       min([ship date]) OVER (PARTITION BY [order]) [ship date]
       FROM tracking;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified." message, you can do that by adding "SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT" to the sub-query. 
But I'd suggest looking into the RANK and DENSE_RANK functions as they're probably going to be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that i understand what you are trying to achieve here. Well if you want just to query this table ordered by shipping date, i think something like this would work:

```
SELECT * FROM Tracking ORDER BY ship_date ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making it very complicated. The query is pretty simple:

```
select * from my_table group by shipdate order by shipdate asc
```

Comment: That's not what I'm asking for.